# NUnit Extension Pack task stop after failed tests

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuildextensionpack

I am running msbuild nunit task from extension pack that has 1 test which fails:

```
 <Target Name="Tests">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.NUnit 
      Assemblies="$(DropsDir)\$(Configuration)\$(TestPrj)\$(TestPrj).dll" 
      ToolPath="$(NUnitPath)"
      ContinueOnError="False">
      <Output TaskParameter="Total" PropertyName="ResultTotal"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="NotRun" PropertyName="ResultNotRun"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Failures" PropertyName="ResultFailures"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Errors" PropertyName="ResultErrors"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Inconclusive" PropertyName="ResultInconclusive"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Ignored" PropertyName="ResultIgnored"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Skipped" PropertyName="ResultSkipped"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Invalid" PropertyName="ResultInvalid"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.NUnit>
  </Target>
```

output:

[image]

How can I  prevent the next target to be executed? "Zip-Projects" ?
I am using MSBuild.Extension.Pack.March.2015.zip and framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using an Error task and reading both output variables ResultErrors and ResultFailures.

```
<Error Condition="$(ResultErrors) > 0 Or $(ResultFailures) > 0" Text="Unit Tests didn't pass *****" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version of the MSBuildExtensionPack you're using, but looking at the source for [Trunk](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack/blob/9da869d07012caa0b6e7315ac5be498b7eb2cacf/Solutions/Main/Framework/CodeQuality/NUnit.cs) (Line 278) It looks like you need to specify The `FailOnFailures` Property in order to get their failure detection to work.

Therefore

```
 <Target Name="Tests">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.NUnit 
      Assemblies="$(DropsDir)\$(Configuration)\$(TestPrj)\$(TestPrj).dll" 
      ToolPath="$(NUnitPath)"
      FailOnFailures="True"
      ContinueOnError="False">
      <Output TaskParameter="Total" PropertyName="ResultTotal"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="NotRun" PropertyName="ResultNotRun"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Failures" PropertyName="ResultFailures"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Errors" PropertyName="ResultErrors"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Inconclusive" PropertyName="ResultInconclusive"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Ignored" PropertyName="ResultIgnored"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Skipped" PropertyName="ResultSkipped"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="Invalid" PropertyName="ResultInvalid"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.NUnit>
  </Target>
```

Comment: I have updated the post with MSBuildExtensionPack version. Also, FailOnFailures didn't work maybe because this is reported as an Error and not a Failure. I can read errors on ResultErrors variable. Any way I can stop the build using that property ?

Comment: @nerlijma Your answer above as you found out is the correct way to do it, in my opinion this seems like a bug in the MSBuildExtensionPack, probably worth opening up an issue on their GitHub to report it for others.